# HHH000489:No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)database created but not table schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-boot-maven-plugin

## my old projects are working fine after I created new projects not even one new works now

**with this the database is created but inside database the table is not created. also when I run spring boot I see no sql queries being run in console.

this doesn't happen in old projects.

I'm using STS

I tried using spring initializr still same problem. I tried using intellij. I tried adding other dependencies also but didn't get solved.**

**My pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>commerce</artifactId>
    <version>2</version>
    <name>commerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My application.properties file**

```
#data config
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

#jpa hibernate config

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
```

**my colsole log file**

```
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.2)[0;39m

[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.465+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting CommerceApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 16920 (C:\Users\coola\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.21.0.RELEASE\commerce\target\classes started by coola in C:\Users\coola\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.21.0.RELEASE\commerce)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.469+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.544+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:37.544+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.263+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.292+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.860+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.874+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.874+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:38.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1410 ms
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.130+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.195+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.237+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.581+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.621+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.991+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@147f7b37
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.994+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.073+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.488+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.494+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.551+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.955+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.998+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:41.011+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.CommerceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started CommerceApplication in 3.985 seconds (process running for 4.934)
```

I think It's coming from here but I don't know how to solve it

```
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.237+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.581+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.621+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.991+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@147f7b37
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:39.994+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.073+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.488+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.494+05:45[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-20T23:21:40.551+05:45[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m16920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

**I tried using spring initializr still same problem. I tried using intellij. I tried adding other dependencies also but didn't get solved

creating new project with difference version reinstall mysql**

Comment: Did you found solution? Can you try to set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create?

Comment: The problem was my package location.
the packages needs to be in same path/location to main springboot application java run program. I created my controllers models in another folder and main java run file was in another folder because of which springboot didn't found the file and database was not createted.
It had nothing to do with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update